# Android App Run Command Recursively

Tags: java, android, runtime

Hi so i'm writing a little app that runs a few scripts I have written the scripts are all stored in a directory and the scripts change occasionally that is some are deleted/added from time to time depending on my server so I need to run a command from the app to recursively chmod all of the files in the directory before the scripts are run i'm using the following code to chmod the files but can't figure out how to do it for all the files in the directory

Thank you for any help

```
//Code to chmod the file
execCommand("busybox chmod 755 ");

//execCommand Method
public Boolean execCommand(String command) {
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = rt.exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream()); 
            os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
            os.flush();
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            process.waitFor();
           } catch (IOException e) {
              return false;
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              return false;
              }
              return true;
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

busybox chmod on my device accepts the -R recurse flag

Or you could do it the hard way:

busybox doesn't seem to have a complete enough xargs command (with the replace string option) to deal with chmod wanting the file as its last argument rather than its first.

This works on mine:

busybox find | while read f ; do chmod 755 $f ; done

It may or may not on yours; in particular, I'm not completely sure who is running the while loop - busybox or toolbox.  On one vendor-stock-image device I was playing with recently, while loops didn't work.  It didn't have find either...